How to Convert â„¢ Back Into ™ With C#
I have data coming in from an outside source. The datasource is converting a ™ special character into â„¢.
According to this chart, there's an encoding issue:
https://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html
So, how do I get C# to convert â„¢ back into ™?
I've tried the following, but I can't get back the ™ character:
byte[] bytes1 = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("â„¢");
String str1 = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bytes1);
String str2 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes1);
string str3 = Encoding.UTF32.GetString(bytes1);

var bytes2 = Encoding.Default.GetBytes("â„¢");
var str4 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes2);
var str5 = Encoding.UTF32.GetString(bytes2);
var str6 = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bytes2);

byte[] bytes3 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("â„¢");
String str7 = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bytes3);
String str8 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes3);
string str9 = Encoding.UTF32.GetString(bytes3);

byte[] bytes4 = Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes("â„¢");
String str10 = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bytes4);
String str11 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes4);
string str12 = Encoding.UTF32.GetString(bytes4);


The datasource is converting a ™ special character into â„¢ - are you sure it is the data source changing the characters, as opposed to you not being able to read them correctly?

@GSerg yes, it's being read in from a file like that.

That further suggests that you are not reading it correctly. Does the database declare in which encoding it has saved the file, and are you reading that file in that encoding?

@GSerg no, the datasource does not declare what encoding is being used.  It is being read in using NetTopologySuite.IO so I don't have control over how it is being read.

Then you cannot say that the database does or does not change the characters. What characters you see depends on what encoding you use when you look at them, NetTopologySuite.IO or otherwise. Please see the link.

Python demonstration: '™'.encode('utf8').decode('cp1252') == 'â„¢'.  UTF-8 bytes are being read from the file and interpreted as Windows-1252 encoding.

â„¢ is what you get when the UTF-8 encoded form of ™ (bytes E2 84 A2) is misinterpreted in a Latin encoding like Windows-1252.  To reverse it, try using Encoding.Default to recover the bytes, and then Encoding.UTF8 to decode them, eg:
byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes("â„¢");
String str = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);

If Encoding.Default doesn't work (ie, because your OS locale is something else), then use Encoding.GetEncoding() instead:
byte[] bytes = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetBytes("â„¢");
String str = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);

Of course, the real solution is to fix the interpretation of your input so you don't end up with â„¢ in the first place.  The input data is UTF-8, so it needs to be interpreted as UTF-8 when brought into your program, not as Windows-1252 or similar.

Nice. That worked. Yes, the real fix is to get the input fixed, but for now this will do it. Thanks!
